# Are C2DM notifications be replaceable?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I'm using C2DM notification service. When I send 2 consecutive notification, I can see only the second one. My question is can notifications form same service are replaced?

Comment: what happens if we frequently register with C2DM by same senderID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand your question, but if two messages sent with the same `collapse_key` before the first one is handled by the device, the server automatically removes the first one. So if you need several messages to arrive, change the value of the key.
You can read a little bit more about this here: https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/?hl=sv-SE#push

Comment: what happens if we frequently register with C2DM by same senderID?

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to the fact that C2DM messages are not guaranteed to be delivered (kind of like UDP instead of TCP). Some services, such as Urban Airship claim to address this problem/feature.